# Activate environment in Anaconda3

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have 3 environments now:

```
[abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
mlearing                 /home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/mlearing
mlearning2               /home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/mlearning2
root                  *  /home/abigail/anaconda3
```

I want to switch to env 'mlearing':

```
[abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ source envs/mlearing/bin/activate 
(root) [abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ conda info --envs
```

But it looks like it still sticks the root env:

```
(root) [abigail@localhost anaconda3]$ conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
mlearing                 /home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/mlearing
mlearning2               /home/abigail/anaconda3/envs/mlearning2
root                  *  /home/abigail/anaconda3
```

How to switch to a different env?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
conda activate envname
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Linux, OS X: source activate <environment_name>

Windows: activate <environment_name>
```